# Clear button trigger event handler on kendo Angular grid filter menu template

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have implemented `kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate` on Kendo Angular Grid.

```
<kendo-grid-column
   field="orderStage"
   title="Order Stage"
   width="110px">
                  <ng-template
                    kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate
                    let-filter="filter"
                    let-column="column"
                    let-filterService="filterService"
                  >
                    <kendo-multiselect
                      [data]="orderStageData"
                      [(ngModel)]="orderStagesSelected"
                      (valueChange)="multiSelectChange($event,filterService,'orderStage')"
                    >
                    </kendo-multiselect>
                  </ng-template>
                </kendo-grid-column>
```

I need to do some operation on click of clear button in my filter. please have a look at the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect/configuration/clearbutton) clear button trigger the `valueChange` event, so you sould be able to validate on `multiSelectChange` if value is null and run your code

**UPDATE**

check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djcare)

```
private previousCategoryFilter: CompositeFilterDescriptor[] = [];

public filterChange(filter: CompositeFilterDescriptor): void {
    let catFilter = filter.filters.map((f: CompositeFilterDescriptor) => {
      return f.filters.find((f: FilterDescriptor) =>
        f.field === 'CategoryID'
      ) as CompositeFilterDescriptor
    })

    console.log("catFilter", catFilter)
    console.log("this.previousCategoryFilter", this.previousCategoryFilter)


    if (this.previousCategoryFilter.length = 0 && catFilter.length > 0) {
      console.log("save value")
      this.previousCategoryFilter = catFilter
    }
    else if (this.previousCategoryFilter.length > 0 && catFilter.length === 0) {
      console.log("clear")
      this.previousCategoryFilter = []
    }
}
```

i added logic to check if there where values selected previously and when all filters are removed you can run your logic

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out. But "I need to do some operation on click of the clear button in my filter" But not on valueChange. Basically, I need the column on which the clear filter is clicked, based on that I need to do some custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for the jquery kendo grid. To catch anything on the clear button click of grid filter one can use the filterMenuInit function inside the kendo grid.

```
filterable: true,
filterMenuInit: function (e) {
    e.container.on("click", "[type='reset']", 
            function () {
             console.log("Clear button clicked");
           });
}
```